# mod_alias.c rule to redirect all subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

***A `mod_alias` newbie here.***

I found the rewrite rule below somewhere and have been using it to block bots and hackers that hit my site, looking for directories like `HNAP1`, `wp`, `blog`, etc.

And it works for that, returning a `Forbidden 403` message.

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>

RedirectMatch 403 /(\{\$itemURL\}|cro|HNAP1|wp|blog|)/?$

</IfModule>
```

But how do I also redirect `/wp/wp-admin/` and `/blog/wp-admin/` to a 403 message?
And any other subdirectory, i.e. `/wp/wp-admin/subdirectory/` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add more patterns:

```
RedirectMatch 403 /(\{\$itemURL\}|cro|HNAP1|wp|blog|wp/wp-admin|blog/wp-admin|wp/wp-admin/.+|)/?$
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're right; very useful. I didn't realize it was that easy. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, I have to wait a day to award the bounty....

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped!